# Show that if $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ then 3 divides one of $x,y,z$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I can do this problem by going over all the cases mod 7. Is there any other way to do it?. I think this way is too long , so I wonder if there is another way to do it or some way to simplify my solution.

Comment: A simple modulo argument cannot be "way to long".

Answer (score 2):

Modulo 9 the cubes are -1,0 or 1. The only combinations that work for your equation involve 0.

Answer (score 2):

According to Fermat's Last Theorem, your equation has no whole number solutions (besides $0$ of course).

Comment: Certainly, but because of this, surely the OP was assuming that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are $3$-adic integers?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Possibly. But there would still be no rational solutions, right?